# Stream files stored on S3 to client without downloading it to flask server

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, flask, audio-streaming

I have a server that communicates with S3 and I want to serve mp3 files to client's browser without downloading them to the server. The files required an authenticated user to access them, so they are all private. 
I'm also not sure if this sort of functionality specifically sits on the server code or can be done through some JS. 
My question is what is the right way to do this and how?

My flask code works like this essentially:

```
@app.route('/audio')
def audio():

    s3 = boto_session.client("s3", region_name='us-west-2')
    file_name = 'some_file_on_s3'
    download_path = './static/' + file_name
    bucket_name = 'some_bucket'
    s3.download_file(bucket_name, file_name, download_path)

    return render_template('audio.html', file_source=file_name)
```

And my 'audio.html' file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <audio id="t-rex-roar" controls src="{{'./static/'+file_source}}">
    Your browser does not support the
    <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your question, in terms of showing us what code you've used, what errors you're getting, etc

Comment: Sign a URL and do a 302 redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return a client app a direct link to the S3 file using [S3 file sharing mechanisms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). S3 file proxying through the Flask is **very** slow and overall bad approach.

Comment: Thank you for your coming Fian, that looks like it works. 
For reference if anyone is curious, I'm using this https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url

Comment: Thanks, Fine. However, this solution may not be suitable for use cases involving sensitive data, where user-level access control and logging are necessary.